# Hoffman and Kunze, Linear algebra Sec 2.4 Theorem 8

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

Theorem 8. Suppose $P$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix over $F.$ Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F,$ and let $\scr B$ be an ordered basis of $V.$ Then there is a unique ordered basis $\scr \overline{B}$ of $V$ such that

\begin{align}
\tag{1}[\alpha]_{\scr B} = P[\alpha]_{\scr \overline{B}} 
\end{align}
for every vector $\alpha \in V$

$\Big($ $[\alpha]_{\scr B}$ is the coordinate matrix of $\alpha$ relative to the ordered basis $\scr B.$ $\Big)$

Proof : Let $\scr B$ consist of the vectors $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n.$ If $\scr \overline{B}= \{\overline{\alpha_1},\dots ,\overline{\alpha_n}\}$ is an $\color{red}{\text{ordered basis}}$ of $V$ for which $(1)$ is valid, it is clear that
\begin{align}
\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n P_{ij}\alpha_i.
\end{align}
Thus we need only show that the vectors $\overline{\alpha_j},$ defined by these equations form a basis.

and the proof goes . . .

> I don't understand this argument given by the author wherein they assume the existence of $\scr \overline{B}$ as a basis and then finally prove that it is indeed a basis. I have a feeling that the highlighted colored text should be replaced as "ordered set". What is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They don't assume a basis but say that if it was a basis then equivalently a property, namely $
[\alpha]_{\scr B} = P[\alpha]_{\scr \overline{B}} $, will hold.

(Note that if the property holds, the set of coordinates of the  vectors in $\scr\overline{B}$ include each coordinate of the vectors in $\scr B $ in their span, following which so will the corresponding vectors. So $\scr\overline{B}$ is indeed spanning and since it has the same number of elements as $\scr B $ is a basis. Similarly the converse uses the fact that there can only be a unique way of expressing the old basis in terms of the new one.)

They then proceed to prove that property.

Comment: I still don't get it. If it was a basis then we know the property will hold for some invertible matrix $A,$ not necessarily the given $P$ right?

Comment: Yes but it is easy to prove that $A=P$ by using the fact that each vector in the new ordered basis can be expressed in only one way in terms of the old ordered basis.

Answer (score 3):

The proof requires two pieces: existence and uniqueness.  The logic above shows that if $\overline{\mathscr{B}}$ does in fact exist and satisfies equation (1), then it is unique (since each element in $\overline{\mathscr{B}}$ is expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $\mathscr{B}$).  From there, it remains to prove existence.

Comment: Thanks! Can you check [my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2286369/theorem-relating-to-change-of-basis?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Hi Bijesh.  This is proved in Hoffman & Kunze, and if I remember correctly the proof is pretty straightforward.  It can be quite confusing when you first encounter the matrix representation of linear transformations (including change of basis), but if you work many numerical examples by hand you will become comfortable with the idea.    Try looking at this page:https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/changebasis/ and working through some examples of your own.  Then work through the proof with a numerical example and convince yourself the logic makes sense in that case.