# Theorem relating to change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

I have asked a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2283949/hoffman-and-kunze-linear-algebra-sec-2-4-theorem-8/2284291#2284291) relating to this theorem.

> Suppose $P$ is an $n\times n$ invertible matrix over $F.$ Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F,$ and let $\scr B$ be an ordered basis of $V.$ Then there is a unique ordered basis $\scr \overline{B}$ of $V$ such that
>
> \begin{align}
> \tag{1}[\alpha]_{\scr B} = P[\alpha]_{\scr \overline{B}} 
> \end{align}
>   for every vector $\alpha \in V$
>
> $\Big($ $[\alpha]_{\scr B}$ is the coordinate matrix of $\alpha$ relative to the ordered basis $\scr B.$ $\Big)$

Attempt : Let $\scr B$ consist of the vectors $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n.$ Let $\scr \overline{B}= \{\overline{\alpha_1},\dots ,\overline{\alpha_n}\}$ be an ordered set in which each element is defined by
\begin{align}
\overline{\alpha_j}=\sum_{i=1}^n P_{ij}\alpha_i, 1\le j\le n
\end{align}
Thus we need only show that the vectors $\overline{\alpha_j},$ defined by these equations form a basis. Let $Q=P^{-1}.$ Then
\begin{align}
\sum_j Q_{jk}\overline{\alpha_{j}}&=\sum_j Q_{jk}\sum_i P_{ij}\alpha_i\\
&=\sum_j \sum_iP_{ij}Q_{jk}\alpha_i\\
&=\sum_i\Big( \sum_jP_{ij}Q_{jk}\Big)\alpha_i\\
&=\alpha_k
\end{align}

Thus the subspace spanned by the set $\scr \overline{B}$ contains $\scr B$ and hence spans $V.$ Thus $(1)$ is valid due to a "previous" theorem.

"Previous Theorem": Let $W$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over the field $F,$ and let $\scr D$ and $\scr \overline{D}$ be two ordered bases of $V.$ Then there is a unique, necessarily invertible, $n\times n$ matrix $A$ with entries in $F$ such that $[\alpha]_{\scr D} = A[\alpha]_{\scr \overline{D}}$

Is my proof valid?

Comment: Take your new basis to be the **columns** of P.

Comment: @user247327 but columns of $P$ are elements of $F^n$ right? How can it be from $V$?

Comment: Every $n$-dimensional $F$-vector space is isomorphic to $F^n$.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with my argument given?